# Can't access object element in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope','weatherService','$resource','$log', function($scope,weatherService,$resource,$log){

var cnto =3;
$scope.forecastholder = weatherService.holder;
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast",
                                 {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, {get:{method:'JSONP'}});
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI
.get({
   q: $scope.forecastholder, cnt: cnto, appid: "7acd7f3379f4ecc2cd8b5068f06e9ff1"});
});
```

$scope.weatherResult.list is giving me undefined in console.

while in html: 
    {{weatherResult.list}} 
it is giving correct result.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: `weatherResult` - looks like it is a promise object.. you might have to use a callback to get the actual result

Comment: @ArunPJohny $resource will automatically bind the results of the api request the way this is written

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console when this code runs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to a add `then()` to return the data.

```
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI
.get({
  q: $scope.forecastholder,
  cnt: cnto,
  appid: "7acd7f3379f4ecc2cd8b5068f06e9ff1"
}).then(function(response) {
      $scope.weatherResult = response;
      console.log($scope.weatherResult);
});
```

Comment: $resource returns $promise which has the .then on it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Use $promise.then(callback)

```
$scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({  q: $scope.forecastholder,
  cnt: cnto,  appid: "7acd7f3379f4ecc2cd8b5068f06e9ff1"}).$promise.then(function(response) {
  $scope.weatherResult = response;
  console.log($scope.weatherResult.list[0].dt);
});
```